# Choose Implementation of Interface by Variable

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

In my GUI there is a drop down list of customers. Each customer has a class associated with it, containing the methods associated with that customer (for instance loading their invoice format etc). Each of the customer classes implements the interface "ICustomer", but the contents of the methods differ.

The calling class has an `ICustomer` property - I would like to set that to be the class represented by the selected value in the dropdown. Something a bit like this pseudocode:

```
public interface ICustomer
{
    int GetInvoice();
}
```

and

```
Class Caller()
{
    public ICustomer Customer { get; set; }
    public void Choose(string customerName)
    {
        Customer = //??? ["Get class where name == customerName"];
        var foo = Customer.GetInvoice();
    }
}
```

From my very limited understanding and muddled internet searching, I think I need to use reflection to achieve this, but I have so far failed to return a specific, set-at-runtime class from the interface. How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: I wanted to avoid that if possible as there are a lot of customers, and they change - I was hoping to reduce the hard coding in the base of the project, so adding a new customer just means adding it to the dropdown and then creating a class that implements the interface - figured it would be easier in the long run.

Comment: @TimSchmelter using enums in this case introduces a [shotgun surgery](https://refactoring.guru/smells/shotgun-surgery) smell. It also limits extensibility scenarios (3rd parties won't be able to plug in a new customer DLL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var type = Type.GetType(customerName);
ICustomer customer = (ICustomer)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
var invoice = customer.GetInvoice();
```

Note that the `customerName` has to be a namespace-qualified name. So if you're holding all your user classes are in the `X.Y.Z` namespace you have to get type `"X.Y.Z." + customerName`.

Comment: Works like a charm! I feel that this will be a very useful tool in the future; thanks for introducing me to the Activator. Thanks for the edit, @felix-b as well - I did get caught out by not converting the result of 'CreateInstance' to the correct type initially.